# Alternative to multiple String.Replaces

Tags: c#, string, replace

My code uses `String.Replace` several times in a row:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("somestring", variable1);
mystring = mystring.Replace("somestring2", variable2);
mystring = mystring.Replace("somestring3", variable1);
```

I suspect there's a better and faster way to do it. What would you suggest?

Comment: If `variable1` contains the text `"somestring2"`, then what is your preferred behaviour for this?  Or what if `variable1` is `"g2"` and `mystring` was `"somestrinsomestring"`, then what would be the preferred behaviour?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

For an 'easy' alternative just use a StringBuilder....

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("11223344");

string myString =
    sb
      .Replace("1", string.Empty)
      .Replace("2", string.Empty)
      .Replace("3", string.Empty)
      .ToString();
```

Comment: How is this easier? The only benefit I see is that it might put less pressure on the GC.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth What I meant by 'easier' is that's still simple in implementation, but chaining together the replace on a StringBuiler is "better and faster" than calling it on regular strings and doesn't include the complexity of some of the Regex solutions that are listed below.

Comment: This seems like it's the most readable of the solutions proposed.

Comment: Not good if setting conditions is needed

Comment: Is the answer 44?

Answer (score 36):

Are we going for ways to make this *harder* to understand what is going on?

If so regex is your friend

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
   {"somestring",someVariable1},
   {"anotherstring",someVariable2}
};

var regex = new Regex(String.Join("|",replacements.Keys.Select(k => Regex.Escape(k))));
var replaced = regex.Replace(input,m => replacements[m.Value]);
```

Live: http://rextester.com/SXXB8348

Comment: Looks good, but you'll want to call `Regex.Escape` around the dic keys when compiling the regex.  Also note it won't technically do the same thing.  It may work for the OP's test cases, but in theory if you had something like, replacing "1" with "2" and then "2" with "3" the OP's code would result in each "1" becoming a "3" and yours would end up resulting in a "2".  As long as you aren't actually replacing something that's been replaced in a previous iteration with the OP's example, then this will work just fine.

Comment: @Servy - You make all good points. However, my initial sentence should have pointed out that this is a bloody awful way of doing multiple replaces.

Comment: @Jamiec: What's wrong with this? It might only have to read the string once, will only have to copy the string once, lets you easily look for whole words, lets you do proper capitalization on words, and lets you do things like escape strings (e.g. `&`=>`&amp;`, `"`=>`&quot;`) without worrying about what order the replacements happen in.

Comment: This is (unfortunately) much slower than calling string.Replace() multiple times.  I'm also looking for a faster way to do this; it seems such a waste to loop through a string multiple times.

Comment: This RegEx solution makes a single pass and replaces all items correctly.  In some circumstances (like mine) this is the ONLY option and calling .Replace does not work.  Why?  Consider the case where variable1 CONTAINS, in part, the string "somestring2".  Then the second .Replace winds up clobbering the first thing you wanted to replace, etc.

Comment: @Jamiec what do you think about this article : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debuggingtoolbox/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance/

Comment: Even if this post is old, I'd like to mention that this solution is far better than accepted one, as it avoids "chain replacing" problems too.

Answer (score 27):

You could at least chain the statements:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("somestring", variable1)
                   .Replace("somestring2", variable2)
                   .Replace("somestring3", variable3);
```

Answer (score 16):

Calling `Replace` three times is not only a valid answer, it might be the preferred one:

RegEx takes three steps: *Parse, Execute, Formulate*. But `String.Replace` is hard-coded, so in many cases it has superior speed. And a complex RegEx isn't as readable as a well-formatted chain of `Replace` statements. (Compare [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007974)'s solution to [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007409)'s)

If you're still not convinced that `Replace` is better for your case, make a competition out of it! Try both methods side-by-side and use a `Stopwatch` to see how many milliseconds you save when using your data.

But **[*DON'T* optimize prematurely!](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-coding-standards/0321113586/ch09.html)** Any developer will prefer readability and maintainability over a cryptic pile of spaghetti that performs three milliseconds faster.

Answer (score 5):

This article [Regex: replace multiple strings in a single pass with C#](http://metadeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2008/06/regex-replace-multiple-strings-in.html) can be helpful:

```
static string MultipleReplace(string text, Dictionary replacements) {
    return Regex.Replace(text, 
        "(" + String.Join("|", adict.Keys.ToArray()) + ")",
        delegate(Match m) { return replacements[m.Value]; }
    );
}

// somewhere else in code
string temp = "Jonathan Smith is a developer";
adict.Add("Jonathan", "David");
adict.Add("Smith", "Seruyange");
string rep = MultipleReplace(temp, adict);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as Jamiec's answer, but without the (required) escaping.

Answer (score 4):

Depending how your data is organized (what you're replacing) or how many you have; an array and loops might be a good approach.

```
string[] replaceThese = {"1", "2", "3"};
string data = "replace1allthe2numbers3";

foreach (string curr in replaceThese)
{
    data = data.Replace(curr, string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use RegEx add this class to your project,
It uses an extension method 'MultipleReplace':

```
public static class StringExtender
{
    public static string MultipleReplace(this string text, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
    {
        string retVal = text;
        foreach (string textToReplace in replacements.Keys)
        {
            retVal = retVal.Replace(textToReplace, replacements[textToReplace]);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this piece of code:

```
 string mystring = "foobar";

 Dictionary<string, string> stringsToReplace = new Dictionary<string,string>();
 stringsToReplace.Add("somestring", variable1);
 stringsToReplace.Add("somestring2", variable2);
 stringsToReplace.Add("somestring3", variable1);

 mystring = mystring.MultipleReplace(stringsToReplace);
```

Comment: upvoted this one.  it allows you to build up the filters say from a datatable which is super helpful.  So when you have many filters (50 in my case) and you have 1k sentences to go through, this is the cat's meow.

Comment: This answer encourages bad practices when dealing with an unbounded number of strings. It should be edited to use a `StringBuilder` in the implementation otherwise it becomes a huge memory waster.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is to use the power of `Regex` to solve a multiple replace problem. The only issue with this approach is you only get to choose one `string` to replace with.

The following will replace all `'/'` or `':'` with a `'-'` to make a valid file name.

```
Regex.Replace("invalid:file/name.txt", @"[/:]", "-");
```