# C# - replace multiline string and copy to another textbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, multiline

I am having a brain-aching problem, which I hope you guys could help.

I have a **textBox1** containing multiline string as follow:

```
filewith.dl_
somefiles.sy_
morewith.ex_
```

textBox1 contains a files that GetFiles finds when the user browses to a folder containing compressed windows installation files.

What I want to do is have the same multiline text shown in textBox2 but replace `.dl_` with `.dll`, `sy_` with `sys` and `ex_` with `exe`.

I have tried:

```
    private void buttonExpandAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(".dl_", "dll");
    }
```

but obviously that is very limiting as it can only replace .dl_ to dll and ignores the other sy_ and dl_.

I have tried `Regex.Replace` as well but again it only does .dl_ and not the othe two.

Is there a way to replace those characters in one swoop? Sorry if this is simple guys but I am new to this!

thank you in advance!

Nigel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007358/alternative-to-string-replace-multiple-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to chain calls to `Replace` like this:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text
    .Replace(".dl_", ".dll")
    .Replace(".ex_", ".exe")
    .Replace(".sy_", ".sys");
```