# Replacing multiple characters in a string in c# by a one liner

Tags: c#, .net, replace

What I'm wondering of is whether it is possible to replace multiple characters in a string (lets say, the &, | and $ characters for example) without having to use .Replace() several times ? Currently I'm using it as

```
return inputData.Replace('$', ' ').Replace('|', ' ').Replace('&', ' ');
```

but that is just awful and I'm wondering if a similarly small, yet effective alternative is out there.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the answers, unfortunately I don't have the 15 reputation needed to upvote people

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007358/alternative-to-string-replace-multiple-times, long story short, unless you want to make the code less readable then, no, not really.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace`:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[$|&]", " ");
```

Comment: And even escaping is not required, +1

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Split` function and `String.Join` next:

```
String.Join(" ", abc.Split('&', '|', '$'))
```

Test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     String abc = "asdfj$asdfj$sdfjn&sfnjdf|jnsdf|";
     Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", abc.Split('&', '|', '$')));
}
```

Comment: should be `...Join(" ", ...` surely?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do with `Regex`, but if you prefer for some reason to avoid it, use the following static extension:

```
public static string ReplaceMultiple(this string target, string samples, char replaceWith) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(target) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(samples))
        return target;
    var tar = target.ToCharArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < tar.Length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < samples.Length; j++) {
            if (tar[i] == samples[j]) {
                tar[i] = replaceWith;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return new string(tar);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var target = "abc123abc123";
var replaced = target.ReplaceMultiple("ab2", 'x');
//replaced will result: "xxc1x3xxc1x3"
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
return Regex.Replace(inputData, "[\$\|\&]", " ");
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. You have to double-escape your Regex or either you have to prefix your string with `@`.