# How can i use the "String.Empty" functionality to get rid of words from a text but for multiple different words at once in c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to remove "and","is","and other words" instead of just "and"

```
original = original.Replace("and", String.Empty);
```

I am trying to create a program that can detect and kind of compress a text file down by getting rid of irrelevant words like "and" , "is", "because" etc etc.

```
string original = "yeet is and this because working is  what help me.";

original = original.Replace("and", String.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(original);
Console.ReadLine();
```

It wont run the code instead it will just say "Name can be simplified" if I do
"and","in" I did try using or as in ||.

Comment: You can just keep doing `.Replace().Replace().Replace()` to do multiple or switch over to something more flexible like regex. [here's more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) Example from that page: `s = s.Replace('a', 'b').Replace('b', 'c').Replace('c', 'd');`

Comment: "Name can be simplified" is just a suggestion. It shouldn't have any bearing on your ability to run the code or what it does. And it can't be referring to any of the lines of code you've shown us. Are you seeing an error in the Errors pane? Does a console open? Please tell us in more detail what is _actually_ happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Multiple String Elements in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321331/replace-multiple-string-elements-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to throw my hat in on this one, too. I just tested both of these methods and they now work correctly (after edits), without removing parts of words as well as keeping duplicate words. Since there's no sorting, it also keeps the order of the words. They also remove accidental extra white spaces between words.

```
var irrelevantWords = new List<string>
{
    "and", "is", "the", "of"
};

string original = "yeet is and this because working is  what help me.";
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (string word in original.Split(' '))
{
    if (!word.Equals(string.Empty) && (irrelevantWords.IndexOf(word) == -1))
    {
        result.Add(word);
    }
}
return string.Join(" ", result);
```

The loop can be shortened to a single line with Linq.

```
return string.Join(" ", original
    .Split(' ')
    .ToList()
    .Where(word => !word.Equals(string.Empty) && (irrelevantWords.IndexOf(word) == -1))));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of "irrelevant" words, you can store them in a list and then replace them in a loop:

```
var irrelevantWords = new List<string>
{
    "and", "is", "the", "of"
};

string original = "yeet is and this because working is  what help me.";

foreach (var irrelevantWord in irrelevantWords)
{
    original = original.Replace(irrelevantWord, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: So long as it's okay for words like "bandage" to become "bage".

Comment: @JonathonChase I suppose an easy fix for that would be to add spaces on either side of the keywords.

Comment: @KevinLamb there will be edge cases for starting and end of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't do this?

```
original = original.Replace("and", String.Empty);
original = original.Replace("because", String.Empty);
original = original.Replace("is", String.Empty);          
Console.WriteLine(original);
Console.ReadLine();---
```

If you look at the [String.Replace Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8), you'll see that it can only accept 2 arguments at a time, either char,char or string,string.

Answer (score 0):

using `String.Replace`, I don't think so. See [Replace Multiple String Elements in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321331/replace-multiple-string-elements-in-c-sharp)

However, you could use Join and Split. Something like:

```
var exceptWords = new HashSet<string>
{
    "and", "is", "the", "of"
};

string original = "yeet is and this because working is  what help me.";
var originalSet = new HashSet<string>(original.Split(' '));
originalSet.ExceptWith(exceptWords);
var output = String.Join(" ", originalSet);
```

Comment: As long as there are no duplicate words the OP wants to keep, this would work.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to @Rufus L, you could define a custom extension method like shown below:

```
public static class StringExtension {
    public static string ReplaceMultiple(this string s, string[] replace) {
        foreach (string r in replace) {
            s = s.Replace(r, String.Empty);
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like follows:

```
string original = "yeet is and this because working is  what help me.";
original = original.ReplaceMultiple(new string[] { "and", "is" });
Console.WriteLine(original);
```

This works and the output is:

> yeet   th because working   what help me.