# Easy formatting of a string instead of using repetitive "Replace"

Tags: c#, arrays, string, string-formatting

Is there a shortcut in replacing characters in a string?
My string is like this:

```
string x = "[\r\n  \"TEST\",\r\n  \"GREAT\"\r\n]";
```

I want to have an output of only

```
TEST,GREAT
```

Right now I'm formatting it like:
x..Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("[", "") and until I put all the characters.

My question is there a shortcut to do that instead of many "Replace"?
It does not matter if it will be a string or put in a List of string. As long as I have the result TEST,GREAT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace Multiple String Elements in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321331/replace-multiple-string-elements-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Why not treat it as JSON, it looks valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like formatted JSON. So you could treat it as such!

```cs
    string x = "[\r\n  \"TEST\",\r\n  \"GREAT\"\r\n]";

    // Parse JSON to a list (could be anything implementing IEnumerable<>) of strings
    var words= System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(x);

    // And join the values back together with a comma
    var result = string.Join(',', words);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Yes indeed this is a JSON. I'm just not aware of the serialize/deserialize. Many thanks on this!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to remove the substrings, not replace them. You can use this extension method:

```cs
public static class RemoveExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveMultiple(this string str, params string[] removes)
    {
        foreach (string s in removes)
        {
            str = str.Replace(s, "");
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```cs
string x = "[\r\n  \"TEST\",\r\n  \"GREAT\"\r\n]";
string result = x.RemoveMultiple("\r\n", "[", "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a helper method to hide this:

```cs
public static string ExtractLetters(this string text) // it's an extension method
{
    return text.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("[", "")....;
}
```

now you can use it like this:

`var extracted = "[\r\n  \"TEST\",\r\n  \"GREAT\"\r\n]".ExtractLetters()`

already a bit better.

Since I think your goal isn't really to replace things, just etract what you want, you can use regex:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static string ExtractLetters(this string text)
{
    var regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+"); // define regex, look for regex compilation and instance caching for optimizations here
    string[] matches = regex.Matches(text).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray(); // extract matches
        
    return string.Join(",", matches); // join them if you want
}
```

To develop the regex, use a website like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Regex isn't the appropriate tool to parse JSON.

Comment: nowhere in the question it stated it was a json. In that case yes, just use JSON deserializer