# Skip a word in a string along with special character

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string as:

```
string str = "= Fields!Change_Date.Value & Fields!Change_User.Value";
```

I want the output as:

> Change_Date && Change_User

I am able to achieve it with multiple `Regex.Replace` methods as:

```
string str = "= Fields!Change_Date.Value & Fields!Change_User.Value";
        
string x = Regex.Replace(str, @"=? Fields!", " ");            
string y = Regex.Replace(x, @".Value", "");
string z = Regex.Replace(y, @"&", "&&");
```

How Can I achieve this in one go? Is that possible?

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23484976/13790278

Comment: The input got one ampersand (`&`) but the wanted output has two ampersands (`&&`). Is that correct?

Comment: Hello @AdrianHHH , That's Correct

Answer (score 1):

You could capture word characters for `Change_Date` and `Change_User` and match in between what you don't want to keep.

Then in the replacement use the 2 capture groups only with  `&&`  in between.

```
^= Fields!(\w+)\.Value & Fields!(\w+)\.Value$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `= Fields!` Match literally
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word characters
- `\.Value & Fields!` Match `.Value & Fields!`
- `(\w+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ word characters
- `\.Value` Match `.Value`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fv4kTX/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/rhdbR8).

```
string str = "= Fields!Change_Date.Value & Fields!Change_User.Value";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"^= Fields!(\w+)\.Value & Fields!(\w+)\.Value$", "$1 && $2");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
Change_Date && Change_User
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to search and replace with group capture

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"[^!]+!([^.]+)[^!]+!([^.]+).*");
var input = "= Fields!Change_Date.Value & Fields!Change_User.Value";
var output = pattern.Replace(input, "$1 && $2");
```

See demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTcIRa)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. However, can you please explain how does "$1 && $2"  plays a role here to give the answer?

Comment: $1 us what was matched by the first (), ie [^.]+ and $2 the second (), [^.]+. These () and matching $N are called matching groups.. The result is (first match) && (second match)